# Is there any standard colour coding on the module for Wifi and Bluetooth of laptops?

Tags: laptop

Regarding the module that can do WiFi and can do Bluetooth.

Is there any standard colour coding on Wifi Bluetooth Modules of laptops?

I am looking inside a laptop I have, and it has wires this way

[image]

Whereas I was looking on google images for wifi antenna main and aux

and I see this picture

[image]

First of all I see there are two sides to the module, one with 8 pins one with 18 pins.

Is the "Main" antenna always on one side and the "Aux" antenna always on the other side?

e.g. the main antenna always on the 8 pin side and the aux antenna always on the 18 pin side?

And is there any standard coloru coding in terms of relating the color of the wire, the black one and the white one, to which connector it is connected to, main vs aux.

If you have a black wire and a white wire,  then is the black one always meant to be main, and the white one aux?  or the other way?  or does it vary?

Also, i've heard that triangles are meant to colour code which wire goes where. A solid black triangle for the black wire, and a hollow black triangle white inside, for the white wire.

How is one meant to know which one goes where or if it is wired correctly, if there are no triangles?

Comment: According to https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-you-exchange-the-black-and-white-antenna-cables-main-and-aux-that-attach-to-the-WiFi-adapter-card-in-laptops  there is a wrong way which can get less signal performance. I guess one can look up the model of module, and see.. I notice that that model of module Atheros AR5B225  has black on main and white on AUX. So maybe Samsung wired it the wrong way!   https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Ra-WmpNxL._AC_SL1000_.jpg

Comment: It depends on the wireless card and laptop if you can interchange the wires. That aspect varies from what I read. But there is no standard color coding.